# How to read a single-precision floating-point number from four bytes serialized by .NET's BinaryWriter

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, binary

So, I'm trying to build a class to read data from a buffer just like .NET's BinaryReader would do.
This is to read Celeste's maps format (which is stored in binary) in a map editor app I'm building using Electron (so I'm implicitly using Node.JS & JavaScript).
I coded all the data readers necessary using the .NET reference source but I can't figure out how to read a single-precision floating-point number, which is stored as four bytes.
In the reference source, there's some code that acquires the memory address of the four bytes as a unsigned 4-bytes integer then reads that address as a single-precision float, that works for .NET but is impossible to do in JavaScript (or Node.JS).
My current class code can be found on [Hastebin](https://hastebin.com/caminoduxe.js), and I'm so sorry if I didn't provide enough information since this is my first question, or if I mark an answer correct very late.

Comment: Hi iiSklz_, welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a well asked question, just a heads up that we prefer code content to be included directly in the question, rather than linked to from an external site. Stack Overflow provides options for formatting code. You can find more tips in [the help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with node.js. Taken straight from the [documentation](https://millermedeiros.github.io/mdoc/examples/node_api/doc/buffers.html#buffer.readFloatLE):

```
var buf = new Buffer(4);
 
buf[0] = 0x00;
buf[1] = 0x00;
buf[2] = 0x80;
buf[3] = 0x3f;
 
console.log(buf.readFloatLE(0));
 
// 0x01
```

where `LE` refers to little-endian. There is a corresponding `readFloatBE` for big-endian.